# Obtain a disjoint union by a union (with case countable)

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider $X$ a set infinity and a $S=(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset P(X)$ sequence of set distints (but no necessery disjoint) at set of parts of $X$.

It's possible get a disjoint union $\dot\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ by $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $B_n\neq\emptyset$, for all $n\geq1$? $(\star)$

I tried to build some unions disjoints, but no yields that $B_n\neq\emptyset$ for all $n$, like ones:

$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i=A_1 \cup\left(A_1^c \cap A_2\right) \cup\left(A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap A_3\right) \cup \cdots \cup\left(A_1^c \cap \cdots \cap A_{n-1}^c \cap A_n\right)
$$

and

$$
F_1=E_1, F_2=E_2 \backslash E_1, F_3=E_3 \backslash\left(E_1 \cup E_2\right), \ldots, F_n=E_n \backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1} E_k\text{ with }\dot\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k
$$
So, if possible, what I should do to get $(\star)$?

If I get this, I can prove that all infinity $\sigma$-algebra is uncontable, once time that I can take a injection from set of sequences of ones and zeros to $\sigma(S)$ ($\sigma$-algebra generated for $S$), but I need the result above.

Comment: Your construction is a good one, except that some of the sets it yields might be empty. To get around that, you could first take out a countably infinite set $A$ from $S$ and assign one element of $A$ to each $F_j$ manually, then decide how $S\setminus A$ is distributed into the $F_j$ using your construction.